# How is data binding used?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have seen data binding in a few examples and I understand parts of it, what I am not able to figure out is when to use mode= twoway and mode = oneway?

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Item" Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
<TextBox x:Name="Count" Text="{Binding Path=Count, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Center" InputScope="Number"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode.aspx)

> - TwoWay updates the target property or the property whenever either the target property or the source property changes.
> - OneWay updates the target property only when the source property changes.
> - OneTime updates the target property only when the application starts or when the DataContext undergoes a change.
> - OneWayToSource updates the source property when the target property changes.
>   Default causes the default Mode value of target property to be used.

Use TwoWay when you want changes to propagate back and forth between the source and target (the ViewModel and View), and use OneWay when you do not want changes in the target to update the source.

Answer (score 1):

Databinding is basically just an automated way of having two values from two properties (often from different objects) synchronized, so that when one changes, the other side changes too. In WPF bindings have a *source*, where the data comes from (typically the datacontext of the form, but also can be specified by `ElementName`, `Source` or `RelativeSource`) and the *target*, the property that is set and where the `Binding` is written in XAML (or set by code).

The `Mode` Property just sets what side changes the other.

- `TwoWay` both sides mutually update each other.
- `OneWay` the source updates the target, but changes in the target don't affect the source.
- `OneWayToSource` is just the opposite, the target updates the source, but changing the source don't modify the target.
- `OneTime` the values are copied just once, normally when datacontext is set, and then no longer updated any more.

The choice of which to use in each case is very specific to the particular need. The important thing to consider is what will happen is you change one side, will have that change propagate to the other?

For example, if binding the `Text` of a `TextBox` to a property in code, often you'll want to use `TwoWay`, because when the user types you want your data to update, and when you change the data programatically, you want the display to update too. But if you're binding a `TextBlock`, `OneWay` will suffice, since the user cannot write there and there is no need to propagate anything.

Comment: thanks a lot but if i have correctly understood this is what INotifyPropertyChanged does? If i am wrong please correct me.

Comment: Not exactly. `INotifyPropertyChanged` is involved in the databinding, but not directly and serves a different purpose. What it does is to tell when a property has changed, so that something else can react to it. The binding needs to know that so it can update the control. Suppose you *don't* have INPC and `TwoWay`, it will really act as `OneWayToSource`, since the source will change, but WPF will never realize or acknowledge it (waiting an event that will never happen). Reciprocally, if you have `OneWayToSource` and INPC, WPF will not even care about it, since it doesn't updates the target.